# How can i share my data from parent to child component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, parent-child, angular7

I want to share a string variable with 2 components (parent and child) using Angular (typescript).
I use this method but I don't like it, because when I update the input variable, automatically the child component updates; I want to update the child component ONLY when the parent component send the data into the child.
How can i do it?

This is my **parent component.html**

```
 <div>
   <mat-form-field>
     <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="city">
   </mat-form-field>
   <button mat-button (click)="getWeather()">
      <mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
   </button>
 </div>

<app-city-weather [testCity]="city"></app-city-weather>
```

This is my **parent component.ts**

```
 city: string;

 getWeather() { 
// I make an http request, but doesn't matter
}
```

This is my **child component.html**

```
<p> 
Child compoent it works!
</p>
```

And this is the **child component.ts**

```
@Input() testCity: string;
```

Comment: where do u call the child from the parent template

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to write it.
I update the question!

Comment: How do you pass the weather to the child component? Could you add how `getWeather()` interacts with the child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Use `*ngIf` to conditionally display data in your child component

If your problem is that intermediate values for the city are displayed in your child component, while the user types a city name in the parent component and you only want to display the final city name in your child component when the user clicks on `getWeather` which passes the weather to your child component, you could decide to only display the city in the child template when the child also has the weather.

You then don't have to care that you get intermediate values for `testCity` in the child component, as the city is only displayed when a weather is set.

**Child**

```html
<p *ngIf="weather">{{ testCity }}</p>
<div>{{ weather }}</div>
```

```ts
@Input() testCity: string;
@Input() weather: string;
```

**Parent**

```html
<input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="city">
<button mat-button (click)="getWeather()">Get Weather</button>

<app-city-weather [testCity]="city" [weather]="weather"></app-city-weather>
```

```ts
city: string;
weather: string;

getWeather() { 
 this.weather = 'Sunny';
}
```

---

### 2. Use a `Subject` to explicitly send data as an event to the child

If you need to send some data as an event from the parent to the child you could create a `Subject` in the parent and pass it as an `Observable` to the child where you subscribe to value changes.

**Child**

```html
<p>{{ city$ | async }}</p>
```

```ts
@Input() city$: Observable<string>;
```

**Parent**

If you only need the city in the `getWeather` function and in the child component you could removed `[(ngModel)]="city"` and directly read the value from the input and pass it to `getWeather`.

```html
<input #cityInput matInput type="text">
<button mat-button (click)="getWeather(cityInput.value)">Get Weather</button>

<app-city-weather [city]="currentCity.asObservable()"></app-city-weather>
```

```ts
currentCity: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

getWeather(city: string) { 
 // send current city to child
 this.currentCity.next(city);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i've think i've thought about it too, i choose the solution number 1.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a separate class property to store the city value just for the child component:

```
// Template.

 <div>
   <mat-form-field>
     <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="city">
   </mat-form-field>
   <button mat-button (click)="getWeather()">
      <mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
   </button>
 </div>

<app-city-weather [testCity]="cityChild"></app-city-weather>

// Controller.

city: string;
cityChild: string;


getWeather() { 
 this.cityChild = this.city;
 // http request
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a service holding your shared data

export class cityService {
city :string
}

provide this service in you app.module

then inject this service anywhere you want

in each component constructor